# Passing an expression into `MoreArgs` of `mapply`

Tags: r, dplyr, quosure

I'm doing some programming using `dplyr`, and am curious about how to pass an expression as (specifically a `MoreArgs`) argument to `mapply`?

Consider a simple function `F` that subsets a `data.frame` based on some `ids` and a `time_range`, then outputs a summary statistic based on some other column `x`.

```
require(dplyr)
F <- function(ids, time_range, df, date_column, x) {
    date_column <- enquo(date_column)
    x <- enquo(x)
    df %>%
        filter(person_id %chin% ids) %>%
        filter(time_range[1] <= (!!date_column) & (!!date_column) <= time_range[2]) %>%
        summarise(newvar = sum(!!x))
}
```

We can make up some example data to which we can apply our function `F`.

```
person_ids <- lapply(1:2, function(i) sample(letters, size = 10))
time_ranges <- lapply(list(c("2014-01-01", "2014-12-31"),
                           c("2015-01-01", "2015-12-31")), as.Date)

require(data.table)
dt <- CJ(person_id = letters,
         date_col  = seq.Date(from = as.Date('2014-01-01'), to = as.Date('2015-12-31'), by = '1 day'))
dt[, z := rnorm(nrow(dt))]  # The variable we will later sum over, i.e. apply F to.
```

We can successfully apply our function to each of our inputs.

```
F(person_ids[[1]], time_ranges[[1]], dt, date_col, z)
F(person_ids[[2]], time_ranges[[2]], dt, date_col, z)
```

And so if I wanted, I could write a simple for-loop to solve my problem. But if we try to apply syntactic sugar and wrap everything within `mapply`, we get an error.

```
mapply(F, ids = person_ids, time_range = time_ranges, MoreArgs = list(df = dt, date_column = date_col, x = z))

# Error in mapply... object 'date_col' not found
```

Comment: Maybe you can `quote` or `enquo` it? This is the thing about non-standard evaluation, it's difficult to program with. The `dplyr` way to do it is (or at least was, I haven't kept up) would be to have a standard-evaluating `F_` that would be appropriate to call with your `mapply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `mapply`, `MoreArgs` is provided as a list, but R tries to evaluate the list elements, causing the error. As suggested by @Gregor, you can `quote` those `MoreArgs` that we don't want to evaluate immediately, preventing the error and allowing the function to proceed. This can be done with base `quote` or `dplyr` `quo`:

```
mapply(F, person_ids, time_ranges, MoreArgs = list(dt, quote(date_col), quote(z)))

mapply(F, person_ids, time_ranges, MoreArgs = list(dt, quo(date_col), quo(z)))
```

Another option is to use `map2` from the `purrr` package, which is the `tidyverse` equivalent of `mapply` with two input vectors. `tidyverse` functions are set up to work with non-standard evaluation, which avoids the error you're getting with `mapply` without the need for quoting the arguments:

```
library(purrr)

map2(person_ids, time_ranges, F, dt, date_col, z)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
>     newvar
> 1 40.23419
>
> [[2]]
>     newvar
> 1 71.42327
> ```

More generally, you could use `pmap`, which iterates in parallel over any number of input vectors:

```
pmap(list(person_ids, time_ranges), F, dt, date_col, z)
```